# How to change a pom.xml version with linux shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have a **pom.xml** contain a line

```
<version>x.y.z-tag</version>
```

where **tag** could be: snapshot, alpha, beta or release.

and **x.y.z** is a number version like: 1.0.0 or 1.2.1 ....

i want to make a change to that line by a given parameter.
for instance:

existing version: `<version>1.0.0-snapshot</version>`

given parameter: `1.0.1-alpha`

output: `<version>1.0.1-alpha</version>`

```
./script.sh newVersion pom.xml
```

PS: pom.xml contain lot of lines start with `<version>` ... so my changes should be applied to `<version>` with a pattern : `x.y.z-tag`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh            
tag=$(grep '<version>' $2 | sed 's/<version>[^-]*-\(.*\)<\/version>/\1/')
sed -i "s/<version>.*<\/version>/<version>$1-${tag}<\/version>/" $2
```

save this as `script.sh`, make it executable (`chmod +x script.sh`) and run it with:

```
./script.sh <new_version> pom.xml
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, i want to verify before if the `<version>...</version>` match to the pattern `*-snapshot` or `*-release`...  and replace it by the given version. your solution it change every `<version>...` in pom.xml.

Comment: I edited the answer.